# How to combine mongodb view with pageable and querydsl?

Tags: java, mongodb, querydsl, pageable

My case: pageable and filtering (querydsl) of nested object (`ObjectB` - not unique).

**Simplify** data structure:

```
@Document(collection= "ObjectA")
class ObjectA {

  String id;
  List<ObjectB> list;

 }

class ObjectB {

  String name;
}
```

**I can't use @DBRef** because of other business decisions. I try to create another static collection called `ObjectBView` and update it using MongoListener. Unfortunately, this solution cause a lot of additional code and stun process.

```
  @Document(collection= "ObjectBView")
    class ObjectBView {

      String objectAId;
      String name;

     }
```

I wonder how to use MongoDB View (not materialized) to create `ObjectBView`. I found out that it possible in dynamic way using `MongoDatabase.createView()` and query pages ([mongoTemplate and PageableExecutionUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46395770/4955934)). Unfortunately, I can't find way to combine it with QueryDSL to filtering data (currently use in project). QUeryDSL need static repository extended by `QuerydslPredicateExecutor<T>`.

Is any solution to create `ObjectBView`, automatically update properties from `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` and make it pageable as wel as filtering(QueryDSL)?